# В каком хуке вызывается хук woocommerce_checkout_order_processed?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Как определить, хук `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` вызывается в хуке `init` или `wp` или где ещё?
Как можно проследить цепочку вызовов?

Answer (score 2):

В `functions.php` напишите:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'action_function_name_1100', 10, 3 );
function action_function_name_1100( $order_id, $posted_data, $order ){
    // action...
}
```

Comment: вопрос же был не в том как вызывать хук `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed`. Вопрос в том, как определить, какой хук вызывался до хука `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` и как проследить цепочку вызовов до данного хука?

Comment: Эм....Все просто. Ставите x-debug. Добавляете свой хук, как в примере выше. Ставите точку останова, перезагружаете сайт и смотрите всю цепочку хуков)

Comment: этот хук получается вызывается аяксом?

Comment: подскажите, x-debug запускается только на локальной версии сайта, к примеру в `openserver`? или можно и на реальном сайте запускать x-debug? как это настроить?

Comment: Можно и на проде. Точно так же как и на локальном